# Cannot use u128 to represent money/price in smart contract model

Tags: assemblyscript, near

```
import { context, u128, storage, logging, PersistentUnorderedMap } from "near-sdk-as";
@nearBindgen
export class MyItem{
  id: u64;
  type: u32;
  price: u128; // This is causing the deserialization error
}
```

When including this fragment of code in my smart contract, compiling, deploying to testnet and calling *any* method on it, I receive: **"Error happened while deserializing the module"**

When I change `price:u128` to `price:u64`, it all starts to work, no more error.

What is the best way to represent monetary value of something (for example NFT) in a smart contract model? Is u128 the wrong type? If I should use some other type - how do I convert it to u128 before transferring it?